# Django - Remove Unique Constraint from a field

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a model like

```
class LoginAttempts(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=False)
    counter = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    login_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The table created in db is like

[image]

However If I create another entry with user_id = 362 it fails with `IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint`. Id is already my primary key, I want to have same user having different counters instead of creating a new table referencing them since this is simple table.

How to achieve the same or what what could be the best way. I want to restrict user to some specified number of failed logins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a relationship that permits more than one LoginAttempt for a User, you should not use `OneToOneField`. by definition, that implies only one item on each side. Instead, use `ForeignKey`.

Answer (score 1):

The very nature of a `OneToOneField` is that it's a `ForeignKey` with a unique constraint.

However, if you don't want separate entries, then update the `counter` and `login_timestamp` fields:

```
from django.utils import timezone

def update_attempts_for_user(user):
    attempts, created = LoginAttempts.objects.get_or_create(user=user, defaults={'counter': 1, 'login_timestamp': timezone.now())
    if not created:
        attempts.counter += 1
        attempts.login_timestamp = timezone.now()
        attempts.save(update_fields=['counter', 'login_timestamp'])
```